# Question on Indefinite Integration: $\int\frac{2x^{12}+5x^9}{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Give me some hints to **start** with this problem: $${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2x^{12}+5x^9}{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I guess I'll be the one to point out that your order does not contain a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $x=1/t$. Then $dx=-dt/t^2$. Our integral becomes
$$ \int -\frac{2t+5t^4}{(1+t^2+t^5)^3}\,dt.$$

Comment: How did you come up with such a substitution?

Comment: @André Nicolas Pls tell us how you get to this substitution ?

Comment: @TaylorTed it's [probably](https://xkcd.com/1201/) the world-famous [*integration by guessing*](http://royalpathtomath.org/docs/Integration%20by%20Guessing.pdf) or the even more famous [*integration by trying everything until finding something that works*](http://www.intmath.com/methods-integration/methods-integration-intro.php) ***chuckles***

Comment: Well, just looked, didn't write down anything, the numbers made it clear. Hundreds of MSE users would have done it the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the cube in denominator, you can say that $$\int \frac{2x^{12}+5x^9}{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right)^3}\,dx=\frac{P_n(x)}{(x^5+x^3+1)^2}$$ where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial fo degree $n$.

Now differentiate both sides to get $$\frac{2x^{12}+5x^9}{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right)^3}=\frac{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right) P_n'(x)-2 x^2 \left(5 x^2+3\right)
   P_n(x)}{\left(x^5+x^3+1\right)^3}$$ So, the right hand side is of degree $n+4$; then, since the left hand side is of degree $12$, this implies $n=8$.

So, set $P_8(x)=\sum_{i=0}^8 a_i x^i$; replacing and comparing the terms of same power then gives the $a_i$'s.

**Edit**

This works but it is just junk when compared to the so beautiful solution given by André Nicolas.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$x^5+x^3+1=x^5(1+x^{-2}+x^{-5})$$

Choose $1+x^{-2}+x^{-5}=u$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take $x^5$ common from denominator so that it's cube it will come out as $15$ and take $x^{15}$ common from  the numerator. Put the remaining denominator as $t$ numerator becomes $dt$. Hope you can do the rest.